# When using HashMap<ObjectA,ObjectB> in java , what is the type of the key?

Tags: java, hashmap

When using a HashMap, will the hashmap store the entire objectA as a key , or will it only use the objectA.hashCode() as the key , thus resulting in an actual hashmap of int->ObjectB ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will store the reference to the key *and* the hash code at the time of insertion.

The idea is that when you try to look up an entry by key, the hash code is used to *quickly* get to a list of *candidate* keys, and then each candidate is checked via equality.

Comment: Why do you say that the hash code at the time of insertion is stored?

Comment: Don't dare question The Jon Skeet... your CPU will get fried!

Comment: @aioobe: If it wasn't, how would the hashtable perform a lookup? I suppose it could lazily get the hashcode of each key which *hadn't* already been hashed, but that seems pretty pointless to me. To put it another way: it seems sensible to me that the hash code of the key will be computed at the time of insertion. What makes you think it wouldn't be? :) (Looking at HashMap.put confirms it, btw.)

Comment: Oh, right. Since even if elements are in the same bucket, they can have distinct keys, and since == on ints are faster than an .equals. Of course. Thanks. Good answer. +1

Comment: does it really store key as well as hashcode ?? I think it just stores key , computes its hash and put value at according place at retrieval time it does the same, does it store hash really ?

Comment: @Jigar, yes, since otherwise it would have to compare a given retrieve-key against *all* elements in the corresponding bucket.

Comment: @aioobe I think it will get hash of key to find bucket and then it will perform equal check to get the required value

Comment: No, that would be a waste of time. Only a fraction of the objects in the bucket will have the same hash code as the sought key object.

Comment: @Jon @aioobe can you please explain a bit more, suppose i insert a key,value pair, it will store reference to key into some bucket and its hash code pointing to that bucket, and how does it looksup .. it seems i messed up

Comment: @Jigar: Look at the nested Entry class. It has an `int hash`, references to key + value, and a `Entry` for the next entry in the same bucket. For lookup, it first gets to the right bucket by the hash, then searches inside the bucket by comparing the `hash` and then (if it matches) invoking the `equals()` method.

Comment: @Jigar: If it *only* stored the hash, and not the key, then it would fail with hash collisions - i.e. if both key1 and key2 gave a hash of hash1, then I could write `map.put(key1, value1)` and then `map.get(key2)` would give `value1` which is clearly not what's wanted.

Comment: @Jon, nop I meant it store the keys and not the hash, anyways thanks.

Comment: @Jigar: Right, if it stored the key but not the hash then it would have to check equality for everything in the same bucket, rather than everything with the same hash.

Answer (score 2):

> When using a HashMap, will the hashmap store the entire objectA as a key

**Yes whole object as key**

It will use key's `hashCode()`  internally to store `Value`

Lets look into code

```
@Override
  461       public V get(Object key) {
  462           Entry<K, V> m = getEntry(key);
  463           if (m != null) {
  464               return m.value;
  465           }
  466           return null;
  467       }
  468   
  469       final Entry<K, V> getEntry(Object key) {
  470           Entry<K, V> m;
  471           if (key == null) {
  472               m = findNullKeyEntry();
  473           } else {
  474               int hash = computeHashCode(key);
  475               int index = hash & (elementData.length - 1);
  476               m = findNonNullKeyEntry(key, index, hash);
  477           }
  478           return m;
  479       }

           final Entry<K,V> findNonNullKeyEntry(Object key, int index, int keyHash) {
  482           Entry<K,V> m = elementData[index];
  483           while (m != null
  484                   && (m.origKeyHash != keyHash || !areEqualKeys(key, m.key))) {
  485               m = m.next;
  486           }
  487           return m;
  488       }
```

Answer (score 2):

It will use the entire object.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it uses the hash to find the entry but the entry itself contains both, the value and the key. That way you can call HashMap#values() to get a `Set<Entry<key_type, value_type>>` which contains the keys as well.

Comment: This is `HashMap.entrySet()`, in fact - values() returns a `Collection<value_type>`.